# How to connect to SMB network drive only when on network?

Tags: network, time-machine, smb, nas

I use an SMB network drive as a Time Machine backup from a Macbook on my home network.

What is the correct way of "lazily" connecting to that network drive so that it automatically connects when I'm on the network, but muting / hiding any errors when I'm away from my network?

I've added the drive to login items but then I repeatedly receive errors like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the network drive brand? Synology NASes announce Time Machine drives via Bonjour, so you basically don’t have to manually mount them.

Comment: @Gummibando ah yep — that makes sense, thanks for your help. For anyone else wondering the same thing: if you have a Synology NAS as long as you enter the Synology user details in Time Machine it will back up without you needing to mount manually or on login.